# All the applications get closed on lid down when external monitor is connected

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, power-management, standby

I have connected another display to my laptop. When I lid down, it logs out but it doesn't go in standby mode. Sometimes monitor turns to black and sometime it shows login screen. The main problem is it close all the applications.

I believe this is the problem related to gnome but I'm not sure.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? 14.04 and 16.04 are different technology for suspend and resume.

Comment: 17.04 actually.